# RavenDb vs. RDBMS horizontal scaling

Tags: nosql, relational-database, ravendb

What are the factors which make RavenDb (as typical NoSQL document database) horizontal scaling capabilities much better in comparison to classical RDBMS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relational databases depend much more on the notion of joins, sets and stuff like that.
That makes sharding the data much harder, because splitting the data is hard.

With RavenDB, documents are self contained, so this becomes *much* easier. 
The next part is that RavenDB comes with sharding API OOTB, so you can just take advantage of that.